# Listen for button while looping

Tags: android, loops

Im having a problem with my metronome application. The application needs to loop when the start button is pressed, and continue to loop until the stop button is pressed. Ive tried having the loop call methods, but it doesnt even listen to the button since it is stuck in the loop. My current code is.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // constant
    final int MINUTE = 60000;

    // variables
    SeekBar seekbar1, seekbar2;
    EditText txtBPM1, txtBPM2;
    Spinner spnTop, spnBottom;
    int value1, value2;
    boolean playing = false;
    int tick;
    int beat;
    SoundPool sp;

    // loop variable
    int i = 0;
    int tickCount = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        tick = sp.load(this, R.raw.tick, 1);
        beat = sp.load(this, R.raw.beat, 1);

        final Spinner spnTop = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnTop);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        // layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.times1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spnTop.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spnTop.setSelection(2);

        final Spinner spnBottom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnBottom);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        // layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.times2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spnBottom.setAdapter(adapter2);

          ////////////////////////////////////////////////
         //Seekbar/EditText//////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        seekbar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbBPM1);
        txtBPM1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBPM1);

        txtBPM1.setText("" + 120, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        seekbar1.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(value1);

        seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                value1 = progress + 30;
                txtBPM1.setText("" + value1, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // stops metronome if playing
                i = 1;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // set the textbox to a new value
                txtBPM1.setText("" + value1, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }
        });

        Button btnStart1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart1);
        btnStart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                value1 = Integer.parseInt(txtBPM1.getText().toString());
                if (value1 > 250 || value1 < 30) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "BPM value must be at least 30 and no more than 250.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // set frequency and timers

                    int tickTime = MINUTE / value1;
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(spnBottom.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString());
                    int beat = Integer.parseInt(spnTop.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString());

                    tickTime = (tickTime * 4) / n;

                    // loop to play sound every specified incriment
                    for (i = 0; i > 0; i += 0)
                    {
                        tickCount++;
                        if (tickCount == beat) {
                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(tickTime);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            sp.play(beat, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                            tickCount = 0;
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(tickTime);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }//end catch
                            sp.play(tick, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                            tickCount++;

                        }//end else
                    }//end loop
                }//end else
            }
        });

        Button btnStop1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop1);
        btnStop1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (playing == true) {
                    i = 1;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Metrenome is not playing. To begin playing press the Start button.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Second spinner boxes/buttons////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        /*
        seekbar2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbBPM2);
        txtBPM2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBPM2);

        txtBPM2.setText("" + 120, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        value2 = Integer.parseInt(txtBPM2.getText().toString());

        seekbar2.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(value2);

        seekbar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                value2 = progress + 30;
                txtBPM2.setText("" + value2, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Nothing happens
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // set the textbox to a new value
                txtBPM2.setText("" + value2, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }
        });
            */
    }// end onCreate
}// end class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you are doing wrong is starting a loop in UI thread. When you do a full-time action in your UI Thread - you block all buttons and they are not clickable any more. What you should do is starting AsyncTask or FutureTask (Async implementation could be easier) and cancel it with interruption on "Stop button". In your loop you would have to check the Thread.getCurrentThread().isInterrupted() so it could stop asap.

I will give you some pseudocode:

```
    onStartClickListener{
        onClick(){
            //make some checks (if (value1 > 250 || value1 < 30) etc..)
            myTask = new MyTask();
            myTask.execute();
        }
    }

    onStopClickListener{
        onClick(){
            myTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        doInBackground(){
            while(true){
                // WE ARE IN DIFFERENT (non UI) thread in this method

                // looping and playing sound or whatever else you want
                // remember you cant do UI actions here
                // when you want to update UI from here you need to do a mHandler = new Handler()
                // in onCreate and do mHandler.post(new Runnable()) here
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) break;
            }
        }

        onPostExecute(){
            // use it when you want to update UI when background task was finished
        }

        onCancelled(){
            // use it when you want to update UI when task was canceled. This is your case I think.
        }
    }
```

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Yeah sorry it was a monday and I had the spirit of "not doing anything" in me a little. Mind was a bit hazy. I can handle it myself now, sorry to be a hassle.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, again sorry I was being difficult about it, I appreciate the work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that both the loop and the event handler might be using the same thread, therefore the thread is stuck in the loop and refuses to relinquish control to the event handler.

My recommendation is to start the loop in a new thread so that the UI thread is left to do the event handling. If you do that, the event handler will be handled on the UI thread and the loop will continue to function on the separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could use threading to do this.  Here's a nice tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

```
// create a thread to execute the metronome tick
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Runnable makeTheMetronomeTick = new Runnable();

// add the thread to the thread pool:
Future makeTheMetronomeTickFuture = threadPoolExecutor.submit(makeTheMetronomeTick );

...

// when you want to cancel it
makeTheMetronomeTickFuture.cancel(true);
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks good, but Im not sure exactly how to implement it into my code since Ive never worked directly with threads, could you give an example?

Comment: We gave you so many clues :P I gave you a clue with AsyncTask class. You don't really need to know super threading mechanism to implement that. Read how AsyncTask works and you should be able to do it on your own. There are actually 2 methods - doInBackground (which is in different thread) and onPostExecute (which gets back to UI thread). You implement these 2 methods and that is almost it. Dont be lazy, we will not write whole app for you :) If you can't make it Ill help you when I have some more time :)

Comment: I only asked because I looked through the examples both here and on vogella, and didnt quite understand where it fits into my application, where to keep the click listeners, and how to use the threads with my existing code. I was just asking for clarification, not the entire code. I thank you all for your answers but Im still not clear on what to do.